# Jackson deserialize json array into single property of one class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json array:

```
[
  //...
  {"name": "admin", id: 1},
   //...
]
```

and two classes named Team, Profile:

```
class Team {
  Profile profile;
}

class Profile {
  String name;
  long id;
}
```

so, is it possible to deserialise the json to a list of Team, but the json properties are mapped to the profile property of class Team?

Thank u very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by writing your custom deserializer like this:

```
public class TeamDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Team> {

@Override
public Team deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    //read the node and set fields
    String name = node.get("name").asText();
    int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
    //returning in required format
    return new Team(new Profile(name, id));
}
}
```

You have to register this deserializer before using it like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Team.class, new TeamDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Team value = mapper.readValue(json, Team.class);
```

You can modify this for list.

HTH!

Comment: really thanks. I tried to find a annotation but without any luck. so I wonder that a custom deserializer is the only way?